# NullReference is returned, but it isn't null

Tags: c#, selenium

So I have these couple of lines of code, I'm using Selenium.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string getInfo1 = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('bank-list')).scope().info1").ToString();
string getInfo2 = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('bank-list')).scope().info2").ToString();
string getInfo3 = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return angular.element(document.getElementById('bank-list')).scope().info3").ToString();
```

The first line of the code executes successfully and returns for an example `James`, but for some reason 2nd line of the code returns me `null` but if I try out the code myself on the site, it returns me information perfectly.

My question is: Why could be the cause, if checking by myself I'm able to get the response.

Comment: A timing issue probably where the script is pulling the info faster than it's ready but when you run it manually the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts take some milliseconds to execute using Selenium. You can handle it waiting the return be different than null

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var result = null as string;
new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)).Until(x => 
    (result = (string)js.ExecuteScript("your script")) != null);
```

Or, in a ugly way:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var result = null as string;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i += 100)
{
    result = js.ExecuteScript("your script").ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) break;

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (i >= 5000) throw new Exception("timed out.");
}
```